# Hilla stopped generating endpoints in typescript

Tags: typescript, spring, hilla

I am using Hilla 2.3.2 and hilla-maven-plugin with spring.

Hilla stopped generating all typescript classes for my BrowserCallable endpoints and Records.
I can't see any errors during the build process.
Some vaadin files are copied/generated under Frontend/generated/ but nothing else.

I also went back to the last commit where the generator worked but still, no endpoint generation anymore.

Any help? E.g. is there some debug logging to be enabled? How does the Hilla maven plugin scan the classpath?

For reference, I am posting the "java-side" of the project as the code generation should happen with the maven plugin.

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <hilla.version>2.3.2</hilla.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>dev.hilla</groupId>
                <artifactId>hilla-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${hilla.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.hilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>hilla-react</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.hilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>hilla-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>dev.hilla</groupId>
                <artifactId>hilla-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hilla.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>dev.hilla</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hilla-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${hilla.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
vaadin.launch-browser=true
spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude=dev/hilla/openapi.json
vaadin.whitelisted-packages = com.vaadin,org.vaadin,dev.hilla,com.test
```

Spring Application:

```
package com.test;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class TestApplication implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller Endpoint (expecting a generated TypeScript proxy):

```
package com.test;

import com.vaadin.flow.server.auth.AnonymousAllowed;
import dev.hilla.BrowserCallable;

import java.util.List;

@BrowserCallable
@AnonymousAllowed
public class TestController {

  public List<TestDTO> test() {
    return List.of(
        new TestDTO("a"),
        new TestDTO("b")
    );
  }

}
```

Record class (expecting a generated TypeScript model):

```
package com.test;

public record TestDTO(String id) {

}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Hi STaefi, the code is based on hilla CRM example and is thus a big project to post. I stripped it down and posted the pom and java classes. Thanks!

Comment: I created a project from scratch with `npx @hilla/cli init --preset=hilla-crm-tutorial hilla-crm` and copy pasted your `TestDTO` and `TestController` and `pom.xml` into the project. My java version/distribution is `21.0.1-tem`. Tried to reproduce your problem by running the application from both IntelliJ and command line, and tried with versions `2.3.2` and `2.3.3`, and could not reproduce it.

Comment: Hi STaefi, thank you.
Did you generate the tsx files using mvn package -Pproduction?

Comment: Running maven: if I run mvn package -Pproduction all files get generated.
If I run explicitly mvn hilla:prepare-frontend no tsx file gets generated.
The same applies if I run the Spring Application. If I edit a typescript file it does not get reloaded dynamically as well.
Looks like in non-production mode, the tsx files do not get generated anymore.

Comment: Did some cleanup by upgrading to Hilla 2.3.3, everything works again. Unfortunately i did not find out what the problem was. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Even though, you shouldn't be facing any problems similar to what you described here, sometimes wildly different inconsistencies may happen that are resolved just by cleaning up and restarting the project. Anyway, happy that it worked in the end!